# XSLT: Change certain attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am a XSLT newbie and have a simple task:

Suppose I have the following XML:

> ```
> <Element1>
>     <Element2 attr1="1"/>
> </Element1>
> <Element1 attr1="2"/>
> <Element1>
>     <Element2 attr1="2"/>
> </Element1>
> ```

I want to transform the XML to the same XML with one change: All attributes named "attr1" no matter where they are have to be transformed so that for example "1" will be "A" and "2" will be "X", i. e. to

> ```
> <Element1>
>     <Element2 attr1="A"/>
> </Element1>
> <Element1 attr1="X"/>
> <Element1>
>     <Element2 attr1="X"/>
> </Element1>
> ```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

You can define characters to replace and replacing chars, then use `translate`.
You can use this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="in">12</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="out">AX</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@attr1">
        <xsl:attribute name="attr1">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $in, $out)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@attr1">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". = '1'">
                <xsl:attribute name="attr1">
                    <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=". = '2'">
                <xsl:attribute name="attr1">
                    <xsl:text>X</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`<xsl:template match="@attr1">` will match all attributes `attr1`, then using `xsl:choose` you creates appropriate value for this attribute.

Comment: To accommodate runtime customization, change the `xsl:variable` to `xsl:param`.

Answer (score 8):

You didn't say what happens when @attr=3 for example so there is an otherwise clause to just copy the value if it is not one of the selected.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@attr1">
  <xsl:attribute name="attr1">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=". = 1">
        <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test=". = 2">
        <xsl:text>X</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What if the values needs to be sourced from outside? Meaning how can an external mapping file be used, which will have `"1" -> "A" and "2" -> "X"` mapping?

Comment: @Amol then you could set up a lookup using the [key function](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_key.asp) referencing the external document.

Comment: I asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065523/applying-templates-multiple-times-based-on-string-values-from-other-document) question to get more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, using `document` function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:l="local"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@attr1">
        <xsl:attribute name="attr1">
            <xsl:value-of select="document('')//l:item[l:in = current()]/l:out"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xml xmlns="local">
        <item>
            <in>1</in>
            <out>A</out>
        </item>
        <item>
            <in>2</in>
            <out>X</out>
        </item>
    </xml>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to use a key lookup against the document?

Answer (score 1):

xslt 2 version below works:

```
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@attr1[.='1']">
        <xsl:attribute name="attr1">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'1','A')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@attr1[.='2']">
        <xsl:attribute name="attr1">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'2','X')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```