# Change several attribute values to new values

Tags: xml, xslt

This question evolved from using the answer at [XSLT: Change certain attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787551/xslt-change-certain-attribute-values) to address my situation but finding that it did not work.

Here is my xml:

```
<root>
<Element1 id="VEH1">
    <Element2 />
</Element1>
<Element1 id="VEH2">
    <Element2 />
</Element1>
</root>
```

Here is my xsl transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@id">
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=". = VEH1">
        <xsl:text>VEH01</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test=". = VEH2">
        <xsl:text>VEH02</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want the output to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
<Element1 id="VEH01">
    <Element2/>
</Element1>
<Element1 id="VEH02">
    <Element2/>
</Element1>
</root>
```

but the attribute values stay the same, at least at http://xslttest.appspot.com/ and I do not know why.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fairly simple way of doing this- just use this template:

```
<xsl:template match="@id[starts-with(.,'VEH')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('VEH',format-number(substring(.,4),'00'))" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

You can restrict the predicate on the match further if needed- add `and (floor(substring(.,4)) = substring(.,4))` if there's any possibility of `VEH` with anything other than numbers after it.

Comment: these are all excellent answers and it makes it hard to pick the best.  I really like the simplicity of this last solution so am picking it.  Sincere thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
  <xsl:when test=". = VEH1">
    <xsl:text>VEH01</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test=". = VEH2">
    <xsl:text>VEH02</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
```

You are missing single quotes around the literals `'VEH1'` and `'VEH2'`

Answer (score 2):

**This simple and short and completetransformation doesn't use any explicit XSLT conditional instructions:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Element1[starts-with(@id,'VEH')]">
     <Element1 id="VEH0{substring-after(@id,'VEH')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='id')]|node()"/>
     </Element1>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <Element1 id="VEH1">
        <Element2 />
    </Element1>
    <Element1 id="VEH2">
        <Element2 />
    </Element1>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root>
   <Element1 id="VEH01">
      <Element2/>
   </Element1>
   <Element1 id="VEH02">
      <Element2/>
   </Element1>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies "as is" every node for which it has been selected for execution.
2. There is one overriding template that matches any element named `Element1` that has an `id` attribute, whose string value starts with the string "VEH".
3. The element is recreated as a literal result element with the same name and with `id` attribute that has the new wanted string value. **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)** (Attribute Value Template) is used to make the code shorter and more readable.
4. In the body of this so created element, templates are applied to all non-`id` attributes and all children nodes -- these are matched by the identity template and are copied "as is".

**Update**:

@wst suggested that the ending number should probably be left-padded with a zero only if this number is a single digit.

Here is the slightly modified solution that works in this case:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=
    "Element1[starts-with(@id,'VEH')
            and string-length(@id)=4
            and floor(substring(@id,4)) = floor(substring(@id,4))
             ]">
     <Element1 id="VEH0{substring-after(@id,'VEH')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='id')]|node()"/>
     </Element1>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on this XML document:

```
<root>
    <Element1 id="VEH1">
        <Element2 />
    </Element1>
    <Element1 id="VEH2">
        <Element2 />
    </Element1>
    <Element1 id="VEH12">
        <Element3 />
    </Element1>
</root>
```

the wanted, correct (as to the newly added requirement) result is produced:

```
<root>
   <Element1 id="VEH01">
      <Element2/>
   </Element1>
   <Element1 id="VEH02">
      <Element2/>
   </Element1>
   <Element1 id="VEH12">
      <Element3/>
   </Element1>
</root>
```

Comment: If OP has `@id`s with values greater than `VEH9`, then this will output values like `VEH010`, `VEH011`, etc - with an extra `0` in front of the 2-digit number. This is probably not desirable output.

Comment: @wst, When you say "probably", this means that you are not sure. Whenever you are not sure, it is a good idea *not* to downvote!

Comment: Based on OP's two-digit numbering scheme, it seems very likely that he intends to use `@id`s with two-digit numbers. Your answer has negative side-effects for two-digit numbers. If that were resolved, I would upvote.

Comment: @wst, Did you doubt that this couldn't be done? After I updated the solution, what next "requirement" are you going to invent? This is appropriate to be asked as new, separate questions.

Comment: No requirement. Your first solution is just broken for a pretty obvious and likely use case. Of course I thought it could be done, and you did, so everybody wins!