# Edit multiple attributes of multiple Sub-Elements of multiple Main Elements in a XML

Tags: xml

So my problem here is that I have to edit multiple attributes of multiple sub-elements of multiple Main-elements as you already read in the tile. These Attributes are holding the positions of the elements and should get edit, but I'm actually very inexperienced and have no clue what to do here.

```
<instance definition="lamp.rect.white" state="EXEC=false">
    <position x="168" y="80" zIndex="108" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="254" y="80" zIndex="138" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="339" y="80" zIndex="137" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="425" y="80" zIndex="134" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="511" y="80" zIndex="109" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="596" y="80" zIndex="119" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="682" y="80" zIndex="122" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="768" y="80" zIndex="127" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="854" y="80" zIndex="128" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="939" y="80" zIndex="129" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="1025" y="80" zIndex="130" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="1111" y="80" zIndex="131" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="1196" y="80" zIndex="132" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="1282" y="80" zIndex="133" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="1368" y="80" zIndex="103" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="1453" y="80" zIndex="135" width="30" height="3"/>
    <position x="1539" y="80" zIndex="136" width="30" height="3"/>
</instance>
<instance definition="lamp.rect.white" state="SW.STATE">
    <position x="1503" y="64" zIndex="93" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="1503" y="69" zIndex="91" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="1503" y="74" zIndex="90" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="1503" y="78" zIndex="89" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="1503" y="83" zIndex="88" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="1503" y="88" zIndex="87" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="1503" y="92" zIndex="86" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="1503" y="97" zIndex="94" width="15" height="3"/>
</instance>
<instance definition="lamp.rect.white" state="SW_LDG28.STATE">
    <position x="212" y="64" zIndex="100" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="212" y="69" zIndex="92" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="212" y="73" zIndex="98" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="212" y="78" zIndex="101" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="212" y="83" zIndex="97" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="212" y="88" zIndex="96" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="212" y="92" zIndex="95" width="15" height="3"/>
    <position x="212" y="97" zIndex="99" width="15" height="3"/>
</instance>
```

So I want to increase/decrease all of the x="" values or all of the y="" values with a specific number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) I happen to maintain, you can do stuff like

```
open file.xml ;
for //position[@zIndex > 100] set @x @x+10 ;
save :b ;
```

Which increases `x` for all positions whose `zIndex` is greater than 100.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer, but when I try to type "save :b ;" I got this back          
I/O error : Invalid argument
I/O error : Invalid argument
 at <STDIN> line 1, column 8,

Comment: @MarcAndrew: Try `--backup` instead of `:b`, but it doesn't make any sense. How do you run the commands?

Comment: open Command prompt (as admin) -> "xsh" -> "open C:\xml.xml" (got "parsing C:\xml.xml done." as reaction) -> "for //positon[@zIndex > 100] set @x @x+100 ;" (no reaction like "done" or anyting) ->" save --backup ;" (I/O error : Invalid argument I/O error : Invalid argument at <STDIN> line 1, column 14,)

Comment: Hm, you're on MSWin... Try using a forward slash in the path, or double the backslash.

Comment: Thank you a lot, with a forward slash it did the job

Comment: I have a question to this command. Is it possible to use instead of "+": "-" "*" or "\"?

Comment: Use forward slash for division. All of them should work, and there are ways how to include any Perl expression.

Comment: So I tried it for quite some time and saw, that for "-" I have to type in "+-", "*" works just like it should, but I don't find a way for division either with a forward or a backward slash.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's [div](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-numeric-divide). `-` works for me: you need the spaces around it, as `x-1` is a valid element/attribute name.

Comment: Hi, it's me again ;). Is it possible to get only full numbers out of math operations and is ist possible to use numbers like `1,8` for these operations? (Thanks a lot for the help so far)

Comment: Use `1.8`, not `1,8`. XPath implements the `round()` function you can use to convert to integers, e.g. `for //position echo round(@x div 3) ;`.

Comment: So and here's the next question how do I open files/folders with empty spaces in it? should it look like this?  open 'C:/Folder Empty/XML Empty.xml'

Comment: Hey @choabra, It's me again. So, cause u helped me a lot with the xsh module I hope you can help me this time as well. At the moment I'm trying to give the module a GUI with Visual Basic, but after I entered the module with the Batch file (which I use to execute commands one after the other.) no further command will be executed.

Comment: @MarcAndrew: How do you feed the commands to xsh? Maybe it needs the input stream to be closed, the `exit` command might be enough at the end of an xsh script.

Comment: @choabra: heres the code I'm using for the batch  `Open MY_FILENAME For Output As #FileNumber
Print #FileNumber, xsh
Print #FileNumber, CmdPath
Print #FileNumber, CmdBerechnung
Print #FileNumber, Save
Print #FileNumber, "exit"
Close #FileNumber`

Comment: So basically, I do start the module with "xsh" load my Stuff that I have predefined and close.  And when I try to execute the code, nothing happens after loading the module.

Comment: How do you run `xsh`? Have you studied `xsh -u`?

Comment: Normal is interactive. In a batch, you don't want to run it interactively.

Comment: Thanks for the food for thought. Then I looked it up again and just wrote the code into a .xsh file, which is loaded with the module.

Comment: Yes, creating a script file is much better.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your xml using xslt. This will result in a completely new xml file containing the transformed elements/attributes. For example, if you would wish to transform the value of all attributes "x" containing value 212 to value 300, and simultaneously 1503 tot 1102, the following xslt could do that for you. Play around with it a little bit to make it work.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@x[.='(212)']">
        <xsl:attribute name="x">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'212','300')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@x[.='1503']">
        <xsl:attribute name="x">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'1503,'1102')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could transform the xml using free xml web converters or download a decent program to do it for you. There are tons of tools to make life easier for working with xml :).

I hope this helps!

ps: I have used the answer to the following question as a reference:
[XSLT: Change certain attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787551/xslt-change-certain-attribute-values?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I haven't worked with xslt so far.

Comment: Happy to help, I'm glad you found your solution in the other answer!

Comment: Hello again, at the moment I'm trying to do the same with XSLT. But I'm not sure how to specify the "self-reference". The code (for the calculation) should look something like this or?`<xsl:value-of select="@x + 100"/>`

Comment: You could use the sum function inside your value-of select="sum((@x,100))". I'm not sure if you can pass attributes like that, but it works with variables ($). Let me know if it works.

Comment: Good morning, it looks like @x is set to 100 and not increased by 100.
             `<xsl:value-of select="sum((@x,100))" />`